# SignalR cpp errors when trying to connect to hub offline

Tags: c++, websocket, signalr

Im getting `transport could not connect due to: set_fail_handler: 3: Underlying Transport Error` and  `connection could not be started due to: set_fail_handler` , when i try to connect to self host hub with Signalr cpp - https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR-Client-Cpp .

I am only getting this error when i unplug the Ethernet cable/go offline. The hub is hosted on localhost:port and it works(the frontend connects to it) , but the Cpp  signalr gives me the errors from above.

Any help is appreciated!!!
edit: i also noticed its falling back to serverSentEvents (instead of websockets , when not having network) , Why?

Answer (score 0):

I had to install Microsoft loopback adapter in device manager and that fixed the problem with SignalR not working without network.